# Integrating Wagtail pages into existing Django project

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I build a website using Django and I need to add functionality to edit every peace of every page blocks on a site. I found Wagtail and read the docs about how to integrate it and thought of the way to integrate it via django views, like this (**main** is an app name):

*main/pages.py:*

```
...

class IndexPage(Page):
    header_title = models.CharField(...)
    header_subtitle = models.CharField(...)

...
```

*main/views.py:*

```
...
def view_index(request):
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    page = pages.filter(...) # somehow filter index page
    return render(
                request,
                'index.html',
                context={'page': page.specific},
                content_type='text/html')

...
```

Is it good way to use Wagtail pages and integrate it into existing Django views this way? Could any surprises be found along the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally decided to use a [StreamField](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html). StreamField could be used to build a Page, like this:

*main/pages.py*:

```
class IndexPage(Page):
    content = StreamField([
    ('title', blocks.CharBlock()),
    ('subtitle', blocks.CharBlock()),
    ...
    ])
```

IndexPage is a Model in Django terms (so we have a simple DB table) & content is stored like a list of JSON's. This two things gave our team an understanding to use it the way we want. To use it in a Django view this code could be used:

*main/views.py:*

```
...
def index_view(request):
    page = IndexPage.objects.all().first()
    return {
        'content': unify(page.content),
    }
```

*unify* - a special method to create a dict from content, because a content is an array where a title live inside `content[0]`, subtitle - inside `content[1]`, etc... Indices could be randomly rearranged, that's why unify is important to use. After unify have applied we can use a content in a template via attribute `{{ content.title }}`, `{{ content.subtitle }}`, etc...